# Ordinary Least Squares: Multiple intercepts with single angular coefficient

Tags: least-squares, matrix, estimators

Let  $e$~$N(0, \sigma^2)$, $x_{ij}$ and $y_i$, we want to estimate a linear model through least squares with different intercepts, but a single angular coefficient for all $y$s as in
$y_{ij} = \beta_i + \gamma x_{ij} + e _{ij}$

How do i put this in matrix notation and find the least squares estimator for $\beta$s and $\gamma$?

Comment: Perhaps you could make your title more informative. OLS is a bit too general, IMHO.

Comment: What is $j$ in your equation? You neither sum over it nor does that index appear on the LHS, so either you forgot one of those things or $j$ is something specific and not a generic index.

Comment: This is not a good idea for a model: there will exist infinetly many $\beta_i$ and $\gamma$ such that $y_i=\beta_i + \gamma x_{ij}$ holds exact. this follows from the fact that  you will have $n+1$ parameters to estimate from only  $n$ observations. this is called overfitting. however, your design matrix will be  a $n \times (n+1)$ matrix "$X = [I(n) \, \, X_j]$" where $I(n)$ is the identity  matrix of size $n\times n$ and $X_j = (x_{1j},\dots x_{nj})^T$. your model then reads $Y=X\beta +\epsilon$ where $\beta=(\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n,\gamma)^T$ and $\widehat{\beta}$ will solve normal equations.

Comment: Hi, it is an exercise in a book actually, not a real application, and sorry for the title.

Comment: Hm, now i might know where the book wants to lead me...

Comment: I suggest you ignore the preceding comments, because they all appear to misunderstand the question.  One way to put it into matrix notation is to write out a small example, say with three observations and just two distinct values of $i$: it should then be evident what to do.